# Creating tables in markdown using knitr: formatting issues

Tags: r, format, markdown, knitr

I keep running in to problems about formatting tables in markdown like the following: why is the following table align to the right but the table after is align to the center?

````
```{r}
dep.vars  <-  letters[1:4]
table.3   <-  1:4
```
**Table 3: Box-Cox estimates for transformation parameter $\lambda$**  

| Dep. variable      | $\hat{\lambda}$ |  
|  -----------:           | :-------------: |  
| `r dep.vars[1]`         | `r table.3[1]`  |  
| `r dep.vars[2]`         | `r table.3[2]`  |  
| `r dep.vars[3]`         | `r table.3[3]`  |    
| `r dep.vars[4]`         | `r table.3[4]`  |  



| Hi there      | Everybody |  
|  -----------:           | :-------------: |  
| `r dep.vars[1]`         | $\alpha$  |
````

I am knitting in to HTML.

I would appreciate some pointers to documentation that addresses issues like this in further detail than the markdown quick reference.

Comment: For fine-tuning markdown tables, I suggest to give a look at my `pander` package: http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#markdown-tables

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a MathJax issue. MathJax is used to inject symbols/equations into the HTML page.

If you knit to PDF, they both center (since your LaTeX code renders natively).

Knitting to HTML, if you change "Everybody" to "$\hat{\lambda}$", both end up flush-right, after MathJax has reformatted.

If you disable JavaScript in the browser (thus defeating MathJax), neither is flush-right.